# Expression Tree issues

Tags: binary-tree, expression-trees, prefix, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am working on drawing expression trees by hand, I keep running into an issue I just don't understand.

My understanding of expression trees, which is probably wrong, goes that you select a root, make the tree, and then if you traverse the tree pre-order, in-order, or post-order, that is the corresponding -fix expression you will get.

So, if I have...

Infix: 
`A + B + C - D`

the prefix expression would look like: `-++ABCD`

and the postfix expression would look like: `AB+C+D-`

and my tree looks like this...

```
                       +
                     /   \
                   +       -
                 /   \   /   \
                A     B C     D
```

Now, I assumed that you select whatever root seems most obvious and make the tree accordingly, so I select the middle `+` operator. When I traverse the tree in-order, it produces the correct expression.
However, when I traverse in pre-order the answer is: `++AB-CD` which is incorrect. The postfix is incorrect as well, the answer is `AB+CD-+` when traversing the tree in post-order.

What mistakes am I making?

Is it the root I'm selecting? 
My method of creating the children from the root and their subsequent children?
Or is it that the postfix and prefix expressions cannot always be found using infix expression trees?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just select a root.

If you consider your operators to be [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), as is commonly done for arithmetic expressions, then `A + B + C - D` is equivalent to `((A + B) + C) - D`. This shows that the root is `-` and that the correct tree is:

```
      -
     / \
    +   D
   / \
  +   C
 / \
A   B
```

Traversing this tree will give you the correct prefix and postfix expressions.

Now, integer addition is associative, so `((A + B) + C) - D` will give you the same result as `(A + B) + (C - D)`, but it's not the same expression. This is probably what confused you.

Comment: So say we have A + B * C + D / E, it would look like.....( A + (B * C) ) + (D/E)?

Comment: @FrankPalmasani If you want to add multiplication and division, you also need to take [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) into account.

Comment: That makes much more sense.